# how can I create second table in mysql? 1050 error

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm creating second table in HEIDI SQL, but it doesn't work.
it shows 1050 error: user1 aleady exists.

I aleady created user1 table and I try to create user2 table. However it doesn't

```
#2. TABLE

CREATE TABLE user1(
    user_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    email VARCHAR(30),
    age INT(3),
    rdata DATE
);

# TABLE 2

CREATE TABLE user2(
    user_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    age INT(3) DEFAULT 30,
    rdate TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Worked fine for me .. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd7c38e

Comment: If you restart your complete script when the user1 table is already created, this error is normal. Launch the creation of the user2 table only.

Comment: Why do you want to have two separate users tables?

Comment: Never store age. People become older every year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date (or year) of birth instead.

Comment: If your intention is to create table1 every time you run a script then run a DROP table if exists <tablename> as part of the script or drop it manually or CREATE table if not exists (an option but pretty confusing if you are developing a script and the table schema is mutating)

Comment: Can you share the exact command that triggers the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this script, which will avoid this error "1050 error: user1 aleady exists.":

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user1 ` (
      user_id INT,
      name VARCHAR(20),
      email VARCHAR(30),
      age INT(3),
      rdata DATE
    );
```

NB: your user1 table doesn't have a primary key and for the age column, it's advisable to store the date of birth because the age can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to write the script using `drop table if exists`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user1;
CREATE TABLE user1 (
    user_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    email VARCHAR(30),
    age INT(3),
    rdata DATE
);

# TABLE 2

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE user2(
    user_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    age INT(3) DEFAULT 30,
    rdate TIMESTAMP
);
```

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` will leave the previous version of the table -- which is troublesome if you make changes to the definitions.  Using such constructs, I have spent a fair amount of time debugging code when the structure of a table didn't change.